# freetds and pyodbc failing to connect

Tags: sql-server, linux, pyodbc, freetds

I'm currently working on setting up a connection from a Linux box to a Microsoft SQL server. I have installed FreeTDS and pyodbc on the Linux box.

I have set up the following files:
/etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[sqlserver]
    host = <ip address>
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
    client charset = UTF-8
```

~/.odbc.ini

```
[sqlserver]
Description     = FreeTDS MSSQL
Driver          = FreeTDS
Servername      = <same ip as above> 
Database        = Reports
TDS_Version     = 8.0
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description             = FreeTDS MSSQL
Driver                  = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Driver64                = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup                   = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
Setup64                 = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount              = 1
CPTimeout               = 
CPTimeToLive            = 
DisableGetFunctions     = 
DontDLCLose             = 
ExFetchMapping          = 
Threading               = 
FakeUnicode             = 
IconvEncoding           = 
Trace                   = 
TraceFile               = 
TraceLibrary            =
```

When I attempt to run tsql -S sqlserver -U username -P password, I get the following error:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18452 (severity 14, state 1) from SYMPLECTIC03 Line 1:
    "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

I also tried connecting with pyodbc, in the following script:

```
import pyodbc
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=same_ip_as_above;DATABASE=Reports;UID=myusername;PWD=mypassword')
except pyodbc.Error, err:
    print err
```

which prints the following error:

```
('001', '[001] [nxDC[reD]SLSre]nbet onc odt ore (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Not exactly the most helpful error message.

Is there anything I am doing wrong when trying to connect?

As a side note, our db requires Windows authentication, not integrated.
I can telnet to connect to the host, so that's not the issue either.

Answer (score 5):

Setup looks fine.  I had a similar thing working, which broke after the server upgraded to [NTLMv2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager). This gave an "**...untrusted domain**..." error when testing `tsql`.   [* detail here](http://www.sqlpanda.com/2013/06/ntlmv2-and-freetds.html)

I only had to include `use ntlmv2 = yes` in my `freetds.conf` spec.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Authentication can be tricky... and very ugly. For best practices:

- Create a SQL Authenticated user in SQL Server to connect with as limited privileges as possible.
- A side note, TDS Version 8.0 will work, but for the sake of being correct, you should use TDS Version 7.2: https://www.freetds.org/userguide/ChoosingTdsProtocol.html
- The TDS Version has changed in 2012 and 2014, but is backwards compatible. I haven't had any issues with pyodbc with 2012 or 2014 with Django.
- You will also need to change this line to include the TDS Version:

  cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=same_ip_as_above;DATABASE=Reports;UID=myusername;PWD=mypassword;TDS_Version=7.2;')

Best of luck; I believe if you fix that, the rest of the stack should behave.

Regards,

-Tim